# How to disable WM_KEYDOWN repeat event for Shift/Ctrl/Alt key?

Tags: windows, message

I have an Windows application treats Windows key events.
The application conveys the Windows Message.
When I hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, `WM_KEYDOWN` message occurs repeatedly.

I want to convey just one `WM_KEYDOWN` message, even though the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is holding down.
Would you please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Inspect bit 30 of `lParam` to see if the message is a transition from up to down, or a repeat of down.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got the sutructure of lParam and have learned that there is a bit 30 to indicate previous status of the key.