# c# - Record audio on keydown

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

The problem is simple: I want to record audio using the microphone when and only when a key is held down. When the key is lifted I want it to stop recording. Then pass this recording to the speech recognition.

The issue is when I press and hold the Z button, It will go into the gkh_KeyUp event and continue to run this code. I want to simply record while it is held, not run this record function a bunch of times.

I want to use this in conjunction with Microsofts speech recognition.

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        Grammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Z);
            //gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.B);
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);

            recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);

        }

        void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Up" + e.KeyCode.ToString();
            try
            {
                RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
                textBox1.Text = result.Text;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
            {
                textBox1.Text = String.Format("Could not recognize input from default aduio device. Is a microphone or sound card available?\r\n{0} - {1}.", exception.Source, exception.Message);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "Down" + e.KeyCode.ToString();


            try
            {
                //recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream()

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
            {
                button1.Text = String.Format("Could not recognize input from default aduio device. Is a microphone or sound card available?\r\n{0} - {1}.", exception.Source, exception.Message);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            Grammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
            try
            {
                button1.Text = "Speak Now";
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                //recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream;
                RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
                textBox1.Text = result.Text;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
            {
                button1.Text = String.Format("Could not recognize input from default aduio device. Is a microphone or sound card available?\r\n{0} - {1}.", exception.Source, exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars();
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Keyboard hook: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: What is not working currently?

Comment: @Alex Updated question

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between real very frequent keypresses and keypresses emulated when you hold the button.

You'd need to use a timeout, if the down was not emitted after 0.5 seconds after up, you stop the recording.

You can access hold state of the key if you still want to use a hook, but you need to use a bit lower level access. You can explore WM_KEYDOWN event and look for a bit 30 of the key state:

[How to disable WM_KEYDOWN repeat event for Shift/Ctrl/Alt key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865903/how-to-disable-wm-keydown-repeat-event-for-shift-ctrl-alt-key)